# Codeigniter session and redirect is not working in IE7 but working in IE8

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm using codeigniter and have a simple user login setup. User submits their credentials, checks with the DB if they are valid, if they are the model passes the controller a session ID and is redirected to the user page. If the data is not correct the user is redirected to the login page with an error message. Nothing fancy here. The problems is it doesnt work in IE7. I'm not sure if its because of the redirect or the session creation. Works fine in all browsers except IE. I tested ie 8 with windows 7 on parallels and worked fine. The weird thing is that it doesnt work with on a pc with windows 7 IE7. Can someone tell me why the login page just keeps getting refreshed every time the user goes to login? I was told to try and add this code

```
$this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $num_rows=$this->login_model->validate();
        if($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $data = array(          
            'is_logged_in' => true,         
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            redirect('admin/show_admin_home');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['message']="चुकीचे युझर नेम अथवा पास वर्ड";
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
```

Login Model Code :-

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model {



    function validate()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('inputPassword');

        $this->db->select('*');     
        $this->db->where('login_username', $username);
        $this->db->where('login_password', $password);  
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        return $query->num_rows;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Also share the code of validate function in login_model

Comment: this code is working fine in IE8.. but when i trying to do on IE7 .. redirect and session not working..it redirect me on Login page in IE7

Comment: there was on trouble in IE7 about session names with underscores `_` have you tried renaming your cookie name and removing underscores?

Comment: Ya.. even i change the name as well...$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 84200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'cisessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Comment: As you're not using the database to store the session data, can you confirm that you haven't gone over the 4KB limit for the cookie? Might be causing a weird effect in IE7...?

Comment: Also, minor point, but where you are loading your model, you should load it at "Login_model" not "login_model", and use the name like such too. e.g. `$this->load->model('Login_model');` and `$this->Login_model->validate();`

Comment: @PaulSkinner: Are you really think through this this code will run..$this->load->model('Login_model');

Comment: @user1254919 Yes, that code will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Config setting

$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'cisession'; $config['sess_expiration'] = 84200; $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE; $config['sess_use_database']   = FALSE; $config['sess_table_name']  = 'cisessions'; $config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE; $config['sess_match_useragent']   = FALSE; $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Answer (score 1):

Add a site url in your redirect:

```
redirect(site_url('admin/show_admin_home'));
```

Comment: To quote the CI manual: `Redirect() Does a "header redirect" to the URI specified. If you specify the full site URL that link will be build, but for local links simply providing the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create the link. The function will build the URL based on your config file values.` So it shouldn't be necessary to supply site_url() too.